# Contact form submit button - disable redirect

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submit, contacts

I am using a simple php form I found here http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/comment-page-2/#comments

But I am having few issues with it. When clicking the submit button I want to be able to stay on my website instead of being redirected on mail.php and just print/echo the sent message on my website instead.

Also I want to make the fields have requirements, like not being empty which I know how to do in php but I must first solve the redirect issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [$.ajax from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This will send a POST request without reloading the page.

Lets say your button is called `myButton` then for the `onClick()` event you would call the function

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).success(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

In your `some.php` you would then just use `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['location']` to retrieve the information.

**Edit**

Suppose you had an input field. You can retrieve information from such a field via jQuery as well. You can just then send the information from the input field via ajax to you php script

```
$('#yourInputField').val();
```

where `yourInputField` is the ID of the input field. With this you can get this information to the script. If you have multiple elements in a form you might want to look at the function [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Does the same thing in principle, just compresses all the information into a JSON string.

Comment: So when the submit button is clicked the info will be saved and then transfered to the php file? On your example you say name:"John", but I want John to be the text that user writes on the input field which has a name code "email". So it's `<input type="text" name="email">`. I am asking how to link the input field name to the script.

Comment: well that is also pretty easy, I've added this to the post in an edit

Comment: Alright, so am I on the right direction? here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjg7W/1/ - and my php: `<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];?>`. The function doesn't seem to work when I add it on the button(no msg appears).

Answer (score 0):

With the staying on the same page you just set the form action to your current page then you could use :

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
(php code to run goes in here)
echo 'blah blah';
}
```

That will run the php code when the submit button is pressed :)

This however will still reload the page but it won't direct you to a different php page. If you dont want the page to reload at all then you can use ajax :)